# How to wait for multiple nested arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have below query with mongodb. I am getting array of exercises from the front end and I need to insert them one by one. And also in every exercise I am getting `sets` so I need to loop again through them and need to create multiple exercise on the behalf of `sets` as well

Here is the code in my `nodejs` file

```
const createExercises = payload.exercises.map(async(exercise) => {
  for (let i = 1 ; i <= exercise.sets ; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    return (await Exercise.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user, exerciseName: exercise.exerciseName, workoutName: payload.workoutName, sets: i },
      { $set: {
        exerciseName: exercise.exerciseName, sets: i 
      }},
      { upsert: true }
    ))
  }
})
console.log(createExercises)
await Promise.all(createExercises)

return reply({ success: true, message: 'success' })
```

But the problem is I am not able to wait for the response. What I am missing here.

**Edit -->** 
Now the problem is I am getting this in console for `console.log(i)` and `console.log(createExercises)`

```
1
[ Promise {<pending>, domain: Domain { } } ]
2
3
4
5
```

What should I see

```
1
2
3
4
5

[ Promise {<pending>, domain: Domain { } } ]
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You `return` from the first iteration of your loop?!

Comment: @Bergi So  from where do I return it?

Comment: What do you *want* to return from the `map` callback - or rather, do you want to return anything at all?

Comment: I don't want to return anything. Just want that all the `exercise` should be created in database and then I should go further in `reply`

Comment: Then drop the `return` and it should work, sequentially awaiting every `findOneOrUpdate` in your loop, and running all the loops concurrently for all your exercises

Comment: @Bergi It works thanks... But why I see this in console `1
[ Promise {} ]
2
3
4
5
` It should print first all the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 inside for loop and then promise object. Isn't it?

Comment: No, as you `console.log(createExercises)` before the whole loop has run and the promise was fulfilled.

Comment: @Bergi I have made an edit. Could you please add an answer for it

Comment: Just move the `console.log` in the line below the `await`. I don't think there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For loops not waiting with promises to be resolved. you should use map. I see you have map which is correct but inside map you are using standard for loop which is not correct in case of Promise waiting, see my example with nested map

```
const createExercises = payload.exercises.map(async(exercise) => {
  return await Promise.all(exercise.sets.map(async (set, index) => {
    return (await Exercise.findOneAndUpdate(
      { user, exerciseName: exercise.exerciseName, workoutName: payload.workoutName, sets: i },
      { $set: {
        exerciseName: exercise.exerciseName, sets: index
      }},
      { upsert: true }
    ))
  }))
})
console.log(createExercises)
await Promise.all(createExercises)

return reply({ success: true, message: 'success' })
```

Comment: I have added a fix with awit to Promise.all inside. Let me know if that works for you, the best will be to have fiddle to test that with real usecase.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help